# Getting information from a specific index out of resolver data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, formbuilder

I'm using a resolver to get all of the model data from my database that matches a provided ID. 
So, I say give me all of the model data where detailId = 140, It returns all of the results in an array where the item has that detailId

i.e. 
    `0: {detailId: 140, area: 4, depth: 1, complete: false}
    1: {detailId: 140, area: 5, depth: 4, complete: false}
    2: {detailId: 140, area: 6, depth: 8, complete: false}
    3: {detailId: 140, area: 7, depth: 10, complete: false}
    4: {detailId: 140, area: 8, depth: 3, complete: false}
    5: {detailId: 140, area: 9, depth: 3, complete: false}`

I want to get the depth value for each specific area so I can dynamically assign the value through formBuilder like so **(for these purposes, area: 4 = index4 and so on)**:

(I was thinking somehow passing the index/area value to a function where it is calculated there?)

```
this.detailForm = new FormBuilder().group({
        index4: [this.getDepth(4)],
        index5: [this.getDepth(5)],
        index6: [this.getDepth(6)]
    });
```

And having something along the lines of this for a function:

```
getDepth(index: number) {
   // return depth value where area == index
}
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: index4: [this.resultArray[0].depth]

Comment: @Vega edit: nevermind, there are instances in which the indexes will change, because if the value is null for any given area, it won't be loaded, so that would mess up the index for any following entries.

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out:

```
index4: [this.getDetailAreaDepthByIndex(4)]
```

then

```
getDetailAreaDepthByIndex(index: number): number {
    if (!this.detailArea)
        return null;

    let filteredItems = this.detailArea.filter(i => i.area === index) || [];

    return filteredItems.length > 0 ? filteredItems[0].depth : null;
}
```